# Wildfly does not support http requests to the server

Tags: wildfly

It turns out that I just upgraded a Wildfly 17 server to a Wildfly 28, the fact is that after configuring the datasource and the addresses to 0.0.0.0 the same as in 17, it should already work but in the case of 28 it should I am missing something to configure because, having a modular Maven application, the server is able to show the front module with js, the index and the login, but when I call the api module by get it returns a "not found", thing that when I test on my local server it works perfectly, it only returns me the not found on the remote server.

I don't know what part of the code I can attach so you can check because I understand that if it works perfectly on my local server it's not a problem with the application but with the wildfly configuration, but if you need something I'll gladly show it.

Comment: Have you checked the wildfly upgrade docs for changes?

Comment: Is you application JakartaEE 10 ? If you didn't migrate your application from JakartaEE 8 to 10 it won't work

Comment: @ehsavoie I don't think that's the problem because when I deploy the application on my local server and access with localhost it works perfectly